# Bulk replace value in pandas dataframe when column has repeating values and value comes from function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with the following type of data:

```
+------+------+--+
| Col1 | Col2 |  |
+------+------+--+
| abc  |  123 |  |
| abc  |  234 |  |
| cde  |  123 |  |
| cde  |  234 |  |
| ghi  |  455 |  |
| ghi  |  755 |  |
| ghi  |  123 |  |
+------+------+--+
```

Elsewhere, I have a function that takes a value from the dataframe as an input. So, for example, `my_func(arg1, arg2, str_from_df)`. What I would like to do is replace the values in Col1 with the return value from `my_func` when `my_func` return is not `None`. One way to do this, is to loop through the dataframe, and change each value in Col1, one at a time. But this is a very slow solution. It is also inefficient in my case, because I only need to return the value of one call to `my_func` per group of `Col1`.

Can I change all the `abc` in `Col1` at the same time? That is, test if e.g., `my_func(arg1, arg2, df['Col2'].iat[0])` is `None` (the value corresponding to the first instance of `abc` in `Col2`), and if not, use it's value to replace ALL `abc` values in `Col1`. The dataframe is close to 1M rows, and the function itself is not insignificant, so I would like to call it as infrequently as possible. I should also mention that I want the other data to remain intact. Can this be done? Maybe a `lambda` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to apply the function on group of rows having same value of `col1` , You can use `groupby()` and `transform()`

```
 df['Col1'] = df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].transform(my_func)
```

Also, about `None` vs `Col1` value, you can handle it inside the `my_func` like

```
def my_func(e):

  
  result = #your logic
  return result if result!=None else e
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I quite understand the syntax. How am I passing the arguments to my_func from this syntax?

Comment: You can pass columns, in this case 'Col1` will be passed (see the updated answer), do you need more arguments? I dont think you will need as they will be static variables and have nothing to do with the row

Comment: This seems to have worked, thanks! I got another AttributeError that I think is from my function, not your solution, so I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Glad that it helped, feel free to upvote and accpet as answer if it helped :)